# ajax validation within partially rendered div

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii

I am trying to handle ajax validation within `<div class="b">` which is is partially rendered by using ajax...

[image]

```
$('.a').click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('myController/myAction'); ?>',
            type: "POST",
            success: function( data ) {
                $('.b').html(data);
          }
        });
    });
```

in controller:

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
    $form = new MyForm;

    if(isset($_POST['MyForm']))
    {
        $form->attributes=$_POST['MyForm'];
        if($form->validate())
        {
            ...
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }

    $this->renderPartial('myView', array('myForm'=>$form));
}
```

If I use use `render` instead of `renderPartial` it works as intended. What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you suspect the success callback, try outputting something in there to verify it's being called.  You may also want to turn your log level up so that you get the full picture of what's happening on the server. Also, try hitting your AJAX POST url with a REST Client or something that will show you output independent of your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend helped me to solve this. Here's his solution:

Rendering result should be postprocessed using `processOutput`. This method *"postprocesses the output generated by render(). This method is invoked at the end of render() and renderText(). If there are registered client scripts, this method will insert them into the output at appropriate places. If there are dynamic contents, they will also be inserted. This method may also save the persistent page states in hidden fields of stateful forms in the page"*.

Whether rendering result will be postprocessed is defined by `$processOutput` parameter which is `false` by default: `renderPartial(string $view, array $data=NULL, boolean $return=false, boolean $processOutput=false)`

Instead of

```
$this->renderPartial('myView', array('myForm'=>$form));
```

you should call:

```
$this->renderPartial('myView', array('myForm'=>$form), false, true);
```